# Herencia en las clases

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una duda con respecto a las clases, esta es a cerca de si teniendo dos  clases (una padre y otra hija) podría obtener una lista (global) que se encuentra en la padre y unir elementos nuevos desde la hija?

Y si es así como podría hacerlo, pues he conseguido acceder a la lista que quería pero a la hora de unir elementos a esa lista los que ya había no me aparecen y no se si es porque verdaderamente cojo la lista que deseo o porque al unir elementos de alguna forma los anteriores se eliminan.
La duda surgió a raíz de esto:

```
class Galapago:

    tortugas=[]
    l_line=drawlib.make_line_list()
    l_sprite= drawlib.make_sprite_list()

    def __init__(self):
        drawlib.start_render()
        sprite=drawlib.make_sprite("/home/Documentos/Proyecto2/ship (6).png",0.5)
        drawlib.set_center_x(sprite,0)
        drawlib.set_center_y(sprite,0)
        drawlib.set_angle(sprite,90)
        drawlib.finish_render()
        self.x= 0
        self.y= 0
        self.angle= 90
        self.color= colors.BLACK
        self.widht= 1
        self.sprite=sprite
        self.pen= 1 #con el 1 pintará con el 0 no hara nada
        Galapago.l_sprite.append(self.sprite)
```

la clase hija seria:

```
class Radio_Galapago(galapagoo.Galapago):

    def __init__(self):
        drawlib.start_render()
        self.sprite=drawlib.make_sprite("/home/Documentos/Proyecto2/microbit.png",0.1)
        n= random.randint(0,768)
        x=drawlib.set_center_x(self.sprite,n)
        y=drawlib.set_center_y(self.sprite,n)
        drawlib.set_angle(self.sprite,0)
        drawlib.draw_sprite(self.sprite)
        drawlib.finish_render()
        galapagoo.Galapago.l_sprite.append(self.sprite)
```

Al hacer esto si mando `print(l_sprite)` me aparece únicamente un elemento
EL codigo que estoy intantando crear a partir de estas dos clases y que por lo tanto me esta dando error es el siguiente:

```
import Radio_Galapago
import galapagoo
import drawlib
import colors

drawlib.open_window(1024, 768, "Prueba Radio_Galapago")
drawlib.set_background_color(colors.OCEAN_BOAT_BLUE)



alex=galapagoo.Galapago()
microbit=Radio_Galapago.Radio_Galapago()
senal=microbit.power_ratio(alex)
print(galapagoo.Galapago.l_sprite)
print(Galapago.l_sprite)

def pintar(tortuga, microbit):
    drawlib.start_render()
    drawlib.draw_list(Galapago.l_sprite)
    drawlib.finish_render()
    drawlib.pause(5)

"""def buscar(self,busca_senal):
    drawlib.start_render()
    drawlib.draw_list(pintar)
    busca_senal.forward(100)
    while senal < (-50):
        drawlib.start_render()
        drawlib.draw_list(pintar)
        senal_1= self.power_ratio(busca_senal)
        drawlib.finish_render()
        if senal_1 < senal:
            drawlib.start_render()
            drawlib.draw_list(pintar)
            busca_senal.forward(100)
            drawlib.finish_render()
        elif self.power_ratio(busca_senal)> senal_1:
            busca_senal.right(25)
            busca_senals.forward(100)
    drawlib.finish_render()
    drawlib.pause(3)"""


alex.penup()
pintar(alex,microbit)
#buscar(microbit, alex)
```

Comment: No entiendo qué es lo que se pretende en ese código, pero como norma general es muy raro tener atributos de clase. Donde suelen tenerse los atributos es en el objeto (es decir, sería `self.l_sprite` en lugar de `Galapago.l_sprite`. ¿Hay alguna razón por la que quieras tenerlo en la clase?

Comment: La razon basicamente era poder unir a una unica lista todos los sprites de las tortugas que crease para al mandar pintar esa lista se pintasen todos a la vez. Entiendo la posibilidad de hacer self.l_sprite pero se me hacia mas sencillo de esta forma y en la manera que tu cimentas no sabria como pintar todos los sprites a la vez.

Comment: Como tu me sugerías he cambiado el Galapago.l_sprite por self.l_sprite, pero ahora sigo con lo mismmo no soy capaz e que en l_sprite aparezcan dos elementos uno quiero que sea el __init__ de Galapago y el otro un __init__ de Radio_Galapago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no entendí mal tus comentarios que lo que buscas es que, al ir instanciando objetos de la clase `Galapago` o de su descendiente `Radio_Galapago`, se vayan añadiendo elementos a la lista que es un atributo de la clase base.

En el fondo por tanto entiendo que esa lista es una especie de "variable global" a fin de cuentas.

El siguiente mini-fragmento de código reduce a la mínima expresión lo que creo que estás intentando. Funciona correctamente:

```
class A:
  lista = []
  def __init__(self, v=0):
    A.lista.append(v)


class B(A):
  def __init__(self, v=1):
    A.lista.append(v)

A(); A(2); B(); A()
print(A.lista)
```

```
[0, 2, 1, 0]
```

Suponiendo que, en tu código de la pregunta `galapagoo.Galapago` sea la misma clase `Galapago` que muestras al principio, todo debería funcionar, pues es equivalente a la versión minima que acabo de poner.

Que no funcione implica que algo que no estás mostrando no es como se supone. Puede ser:

- Que `galapagoo.Galapago` no sea lo mismo que `Galapago`
- Que la clase `Galapago` sea definida dos veces (y cada vez se re-crea su lista)
- Algún detalle en la instanciación de los objetos (?)
- Que la lista que intentas imprimir con el `print()` no sea `Galapago.l_sprite`

Comment: Muchas gracias, efectivamente eso es lo que trataba de hacer pero como tu dices debo de tener algun error pues me sigue apareciendo unicamente un elemento. galapagoo.Galpago si es lo mismo que Galapago, que la clase este definida dos veces no creo, a lo mejor es algo como tu dices de la instanciación de objetos porque la lista que trato de imprimir la llamo de esta forma print(galapagoo.Galapago.l_sprite). Pero es que no veo en que puedo estar cometiendo el fallo

Comment: Si pudieras subir el código completo a algún pastebin, o github, o Gist... para que pueda echarle yo un vistazo a ver si lo descubro

Comment: Eso es todo lo que tengo con respecto a la lista te puedo subir el resto del codigo pero apenas afecta a esta. Puede ser que como estan en dos ficheros distintos cada clase el l_sprite cree uno nuevo? De todas formas te subo el codigo que estoy intentando crear y que me da dicho error( te lo dejo arriba)

Comment: Cuando ejeecuto ese codigo y mando imprimir la lista no me sale una lista me sale:   <arcade.sprite_list.SpriteList object at 0x7fba7aea2898>
<arcade.sprite_list.SpriteList object at 0x7fba7aea2898>
como ves me aparece dos veces el mismo elemento

Comment: No es posible para mi tratar de replicar el problema para comprenderlo, pues haces uso de librerías como `drawlib` que no sé dónde obtener. Y parece que ese detalle podría ser relevante, ya que la lista en cuestión es creada mediante `drawlib.make_sprite_list()`, por lo que sería importante conocer qué hace exactamente un `.append()` sobre ese tipo de objeto. Quizás no sea una lista normal y sólo pueda albergar un elemento? No le encuentro sentido, pero vete tú a saber...

Comment: ¡Espera que he tenido una idea! Cuando haces `print(Galapago.l_sprite)` y ves `<arcade.sprite_list.SpriteList object at 0x7fba7aea2898>` ¿es ese el elemento que crees que hay en la lista? ¡No! Esa es la referencia que apunta a la lista, pero no sus contenidos. Ya que no es una lista normal, pero al menos se comporta como si lo fuera al tener un método `.append()`, probablemente tenga también un iterador que permita ver sus contenidos. Intenta `print(list(Galapago.l_sprite))`

Comment: No, pueden añadir mas de un elemento no la he adjuntado porque es un fichero que yo no puedo tocar para hacer el ejecicio y cuyo contenido yo no entiendo pero supuestamente no hace falta entenderlo para realizar el ejercicio.                                                                                                         
  def make_sprite_list():
    """Returns a sprite list to which sprites created with
    make_sprite() can be appended. The whole list can be drawn
    with draw_list()

    """
    return arcade.SpriteList()

Comment: Ah, parece que esa lista fue creada con la biblioteca `arcade`. Intenta entonces mostrarla con `print(Galapago.l_sprite.sprite_list)`  (pues es en ese atributo interno donde `arcade` guarda realmente su lista, como puede verse [aqui](http://arcade.academy/_modules/arcade/sprite_list.html#SpriteList.append))

Comment: He hecho lo que me has sugerido y si!! me sale la siguiente lista:   [<arcade.sprite.Sprite object at 0x7f6f170a95f8>, <arcade.sprite.Sprite object at 0x7f6f170a9320>, <arcade.sprite.Sprite object at 0x7f6f08217748>]
Muchas gracias ahora tendre que averiguar por que me salen tres elementos y por que cuando mando que aparezcan en pantalla esos elementos solo me aparece uno. Muchas gracias!!!